# Keeping jQuery mobile hash parameters in the address bar

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a site using jQuery mobile which uses URL-encoded parameters in the hash for dynamically loading page content.

So I have a link to a page which looks a little bit like this:

```
<a href="#article?id=123" data-transition="slidefade">Go to article #123</a>
```

And it works, but the URL in the address bar looses the `?` and everything after it. This means that copy-pasting the URL from the address bar, and browser bookmarks won't work.

Copying the URL from the `<a>` and navigating to it manually works just fine - no issues.

Why does clicking on the button not work as expected and is there a way to fix it?

Comment: JQM still does not support query params. Also, I don't think query params are valid in the hashtag and I know '?' is not allowed in HTML id attribute, so for starters make sure there are no ? in the id, JQM stores on a page

Comment: I recently created a [plug-in](https://github.com/CameronAskew/jquery.mobile.paramsHandler) which solves your problem. Let me know if it works for you!